# Фильтр с partition by

Tags: sql, postgresql, оконные-функции

```sql
select a.film_id, a.first_actor, count(*) over (partition by film_id order by first_actor) as mono from a
where mono>1
order by first_actor
```

есть код, но он не работает в части where mono>1 
как же мне удалить те строки? где mono 1?

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий Извините, а почему вы решили удалить метку [оконные-функции]?  Ведь вопрос собственно о них.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, отфильтровать в одном запросе по результатам
оконных функций нельзя, так как оконные функции вычисляются
*после* вычисления `WHERE` и `HAVING`.
Используйте подзапрос:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (
         SELECT a.film_id
              , a.first_actor
              , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY film_id ORDER BY first_actor) AS mono
           FROM a
          ORDER BY first_actor
       ) AS t
 WHERE mono > 1
;
```